# Kohana 3.3 Model not loading on linux, but will on Windows

Tags: php, kohana

So I am struggling migrating to a linux server. I get the error

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_Game' not found
```

My file structure is

```
application/classes/Model/game.php
```

And the model definition is

```
class Model_Game extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'game';
    protected $_primary_key = 'game_id';

    ...
}
```

This works in my windows environment, but not in my linux environment. From my understanding this is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow PSR-0 naming: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#psr-0-support-fileclass-naming-conventions and http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions#class-names-and-file-location

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the filename  to `Game.php` (uppercase "G").

Linux filesystems are case sensitive

Comment: thanks for the reply. I thought that kohana requires the file paths to be lower case for their auto loading, is this not the case?

Comment: @neolaser I was initially incorrect. I've now updated my answer

Comment: @zombor Ah, then the first version of my answer applies. Reverting now