# Kohana - has_many and belongs_to not working properly

Tags: php, kohana, relationship, kohana-3

I am using Kohana 3.3 and am trying to establish relationship on my ORM tables using `has_many` and `belongs_to` . I have a `users` table which is defined as below

[image]

I have another table `userjobs` defined as below. The `userjobs` have a foreign key referencing `user_id` from `users.

[image]

In the class `Model_User` (`extends Model_Auth_User`), I have defined the relationship like

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'user_tokens' => array('model' => 'user_token'),
    'roles' => array('model' => 'role', 'through'=> 'roles_users'),
    'jobs' =>  array('model' => 'Userjob','foreign_key' => 'user_id' ),
);
```

and in the class `Model_Userjob` (`extends ORM`), the following statement is written

```
protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'user' => array('model' => 'user')
);
```

However, when i try to access the jobs like below, it is throwing an exception which says that `jobs` is not defined in `Model_User`

```
Auth::instance()->get_user()->jobs;
```

I had tried dumped values of the `get_user()` it is not showing jobs in the `protected $_has_many` array.

I even tried removing `user_tokens` and `roles` from the `$_has_many`, but still `has_many` array still holds the entry for roles and user_tokens when -i printed values of `get_user`.

[image]

Comment: What db driver are you using? Are you sure your specific `Model_User` is actually used and not the default one?

Comment: 'driver' => 'ORM' is defined in Auth.php. Is this the information you need?

Comment: @kingkero , please tell me how can i check that. sorry, i am a complete newbie to the kohana scene.

Comment: I have certain rules defined in the Model_User and it is working as expected, i even tried putting a message inside rules method, and it got printed out.

Comment: It is set as MySQL for the primary

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time, do ask me if you require more data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kohana 3.3 Model not loading on linux, but will on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192434/kohana-3-3-model-not-loading-on-linux-but-will-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that you should set relationship in user model like this:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'user_tokens' => array('model' => 'user_token'),
    'roles' => array('model' => 'role', 'through'=> 'roles_users')
);
protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'jobs' =>  array('model' => 'userjob','foreign_key' => 'user_id' )
);
```

and in job model:

```
protected $_has_one = array(
    'user' => array('model' => 'userjob', 'foreign_key' => 'user_id')
);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? As far as I can tell, a user is supposed to _have many_ jobs ;)

Comment: Can you please direct me to a working example that demonstrates the usage of has_many , if anything is available in the web?

Comment: I just checked  the code and found that there is an $_has_many  in the base class Model_Auth_User which have relationship for user_tokens and roles. I believe it is that variables are being used and the variables in my class is getting ignored. any clues what could be the reason for it?

Comment: @kingkero  the problem was exactly what you said, My filename was starting with a lowercase 'u'ser.php, so that cascading file system was not loading it after kohana's User.php .. It is fixed now. If you can write it as an reply i can mark it as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add '->find_all()' at the end of that line. Otherwise jobs will be seen as a col.

```
Auth::instance()->get_user()->jobs->find_all();
```